# How do I change directory and run a file in that directory in powershell?

Tags: powershell, command, powershell-2.0

For example, i want to run cygwin.bat which is located in the c:/cygwin/ directory...

I tried the following but got an error:

> cd c:/cygwin ./cygwin.bat

Comment: thank you, i m aware that it can be done in two lines seperately, i was just wondering if and how it can be run on a single line ... I am starting to learn powershell btw so thats the shell im using.

Comment: See my answer, I expanded it from my comment with an example for the behavior you're interested in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`cd c:/cygwin` and `./cygwin.bat` are two different statements.  You can execute them from the interactive console like so:

```
PS C:\>       cd c:/cygwin 
PS C:\cygwin> ./cygwin.bat
```

Or, if you really want to do it on the same line, then use a `;` between them to indicate separate statements.

```
cd c:/cygwin ; ./cygwin.bat
```

Answer (score 4):

best way is the way its always been

```
c:\cygwin\cygwin.bat
```

it's all you need to type

Comment: How the **** didn't i think of that...haha. probably cause i thought i could only run a file by typing " ./ " in front of it..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try iex

```
$command = "cd c:/cywin"
iex $command
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , but i actually want to run cygwin.bat in the cygwin folder... your command only seems to redirect me from my home path to the cygwin path just like using : cd c:/cygwin